# How to test balance change of my staking program

Tags: staking, testing, spl-associated-token-account

I am following a tutorial to make a staking app and I want to test the functionality of my instruction. I have tried "getTokenAccountBalance", but it remain unchanged before and after the rpc call.

I wonder how to correctly test the balance change after we do the transfer call.

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn stake(ctx: Context<Stake>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        // Because we are staking, the stake info should be changed -> mut
        let stake_info = &mut ctx.accounts.stake_info_account;
        // Case:
        //  + user stake, but no token to stake
        //  + try to stake, already stake
        //  + try to destake, but not actually stake anything
        if stake_info.is_staked {
            return Err(ErrorCode::IsStaked.into());
        }
        if amount == 0 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::NoTokens.into());
        }
        let clock = Clock::get()?;
        stake_info.stake_at_slot = clock.slot;
        stake_info.is_staked = true;

        let stake_amount = amount
            .checked_mul(10u64.pow(ctx.accounts.mint.decimals as u32))
            .unwrap();
        // Transfer from user account to the stake account
        transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.stake_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            stake_amount,
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init_if_needed,
        seeds = [constants::VAULT_SEED],
        bump,
        payer = signer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority= token_vault_account,
    )]
    pub token_vault_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Stake<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed, 
        seeds = [
            constants::STAKE_INFO_SEED,
            signer.key.as_ref()],
            bump, 
            payer = signer,
            space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<StakeInfo>()
    )]
    pub stake_info_account: Account<'info, StakeInfo>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed, 
        seeds = [constants::TOKEN_SEED, signer.key.as_ref()],
        bump, 
        payer = signer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = stake_account
    )]
    pub stake_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut, 
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = signer,
    )]
    pub user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
#[account]
pub struct StakeInfo {
    pub stake_at_slot: u64, //what slot they stake(source of truth of time, not timestamp)
    pub is_staked: bool,
}
#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Token are already staked")]
    IsStaked,
    #[msg("Token not staked")]
    NotStaked,
    #[msg("No token to stake")]
    NoTokens,
}
```

tests:

```
  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    await createMintToken();
    let [vaultAccount] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("vault")],
      program.programId
    );
    const tx = await program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        signer: payer.publicKey, // payer,
        tokenVaultAccount: vaultAccount,
        mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
  it("stake", async () => {
    let userTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      payer.payer,
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      payer.publicKey
    );
    await mintTo(
      connection,
      payer.payer,
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      userTokenAccount.address,
      payer.payer,
      1e11
    );
    // Stake info account
    let [stakeInfo] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("stake_info"), payer.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );
    // Stake account
    let [stakeAccount] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("token"), payer.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );

    await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      payer.payer,
      mintKeypair.publicKey,
      payer.publicKey
    );
    // Gold token vault
    // let balanceBefore = await connection.getTokenAccountBalance(stakeAccount);
    // console.log(balanceBefore);
    const tx = await program.methods
      .stake(new anchor.BN(1))
      .signers([payer.payer])
      .accounts({
        stakeInfoAccount: stakeInfo,
        stakeAccount: stakeAccount,
        userTokenAccount: userTokenAccount.address,
        mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();
    let balanceAfter = await connection.getTokenAccountBalance(
      userTokenAccount.address
    );
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
    console.log(balanceAfter);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know the .rpc method, but might be related to confirmation status ?
try to wait for transaction's confirmation before checking again ?

Comment: or maybe the `connection` and the `provider` that the `program` was created from has got different commitment levels? Like to try to use the `program.provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance` instead of the `connection.getTokenAccountBalance`?

Comment: ```const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const payer = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  const connection = new Connection("http://127.0.0.1:8899", "confirmed");``` I set the commitment level to "confirmed", not sure if it is relevant or not